# Configuration on demand is not supported by the current version of the Android Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

This is what i've set:

```
File > Project Structure > Project > Project SDK = 10 (java version "10.0.1")
File > Project Structure > Project > Project Language level = SDK default (10 - Local variable type inference)
File > Project Structure > Modules > app > Module SDK = Project SDK (10)
Gradle Scripts > gradle.properties > org.gradle.configureondemand=false
Gradle Scripts > gradle-wrapper.properties > org.gradle.configureondemand=false
```

and still I am getting error:

```
Configuration on demand is not supported by the current version of the Android Gradle plugin since you are using Gradle version 4.6 or above. Suggestion: disable configuration on demand by setting org.gradle.configureondemand=false in your gradle.properties file or use a Gradle version less than 4.6.
```

What is wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Do this following settings

File --> Settings --> Build,Execution,Development --> Compiler

Untick or Deselect Configure on demand option